# Send Json object parameter to Web Api controller in .netCore

Tags: json, ajax, string, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

This is Google API - Javascript code

```
var output = new Object();
output.PlaceID = place.place_id;
output.Longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
output.Latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();

$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: 'api/StorePlaces/Get',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "value":output },
    success: function (result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

How to receive at the controller

```
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpPost("{PlaceDetails}")]
    public string Get(PlaceDetails value)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

In this case I get null value

I was unable to send the string , if I can send the Object as such, it is better.

This can be used as receiving object

```
public class PlaceDetails
{
    public string PlaceID { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: change request type in ajax to 'POST' and change your method To accept  POST  and change parameter type to 'PlaceDetails'

Comment: @Dalton I get null value, what to do

Comment: Modify data: put `data:output` and remove `[FromBody]`

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan: Also please don't edit the question with things you've tried since the initial question as it may completely change the meaning of the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code, maybe consult a few beginner tutorials first?

First, you have to look at the object your are sending, it's very obvious!

You are sending

```
{
    "value" : {
        "PlaceID" : "",
        "Longitude " : "",
        "Latitude " : ""
    }
}
```

Where the expected answer is

```
{
    "PlaceID" : "",
    "Longitude " : "",
    "Latitude " : ""
}
```

So you have to use this in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: 'api/StorePlaces/Get',
    type: 'POST',
    // do not wrap it in object with value property here!!!!
    data: JSON.stringify(output),
    success: function (result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Second, your Controller action (why the hell is it called `Get` when it's a post request?)... the `[HttPost("{PlaceDetails}")]` attribute is plain wrong.

This would expect a `PlaceDetails` parameter in the route. You don't such one! Just remove it. Also, the `[FromBody]` attribute is missing to tell it to deserialize the model from the http request body

```
[HttpPost]
public string Get([FromBody]PlaceDetails value)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Comment: Yes good answer, but does the hyperbole about being a beginner help him out in anyway? Will it help others to see thinly veiled insults? Does it really make you feel better?